# Custom tableview scrolling effect like google primer

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Google Primer app for iOS has a table view scrolling effect where the cells stack on top of each other while scrolling. [Primer application](https://www.yourprimer.com/) : you can kinda see the effect if you scroll on their page... The effect I am talking about is in the featured lessons of Primer. I am trying to reproduce it with a tableview.

I have tried playing with the frame of the cell on the viewdidscroll event. 
I got it working but it gets very jumpy/jerky when moving up in a certain way. Also, when the jerk happens, the frame gets offset incorrectly. I was only able to do it on the frame of a label inside the cells. My cells are really big(more then half of the screen).

**How can I eliminate the jumping/jerk ? How can I animate the container view position instead of the label position ?**

Current animation on the scrollViewDidScroll with a label :

```
override func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if (self.tableView.contentOffset.y < 0) { return }

    let offsetYDifference =  oldYOffset - self.tableView.contentOffset.y 
    oldYOffset = self.tableView.contentOffset.y

    let cell = self.tableView.visibleCells.first!

    var newOriginY = (cell.textLabel?.frame.origin.y)! - offsetYDifference
    if (newOriginY < 0) { //Cells get reused.
        newOriginY = newOriginY + cell.frame.height
    }

    cell.textLabel?.frame = CGRect(x: (cell.textLabel?.frame.origin.x)!,
        y: newOriginY,
        width: (cell.textLabel?.frame.width)!,
        height: (cell.textLabel?.frame.height)!)
}
```

[Custom paging-like behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12271621/uitableview-with-custom-paging-like-behaviour) with paging enabled set to off on the storyboard :

```
override func scrollViewWillEndDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {

    let offsety = targetContentOffset.memory.y
    var smallestCellDiffToContentOffset = abs(offsety - (self.tableView.visibleCells.first?.frame.origin.y)!)

    var closestCellOrigin = self.tableView.visibleCells.first?.frame.origin.y

    self.tableView.visibleCells.forEach { (cell) -> () in
        if (abs(offsety - cell.frame.origin.y) <= smallestCellDiffToContentOffset) {
            smallestCellDiffToContentOffset = abs(offsety - cell.frame.origin.y)
            closestCellOrigin = cell.frame.origin.y
        }
    }
    targetContentOffset.memory.y = closestCellOrigin!
}
```

I am a beginner swift developper and I am really clueless on what the do. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In essence what you're seeing is the `UITableView` is resisting your efforts to create this animation. Rightly so, changing the frame of the cell should be left to the tableview itself.

What you instead need is a `UICollectionView` with a custom layout object that controls the position of the cells. This'll be a fair bit of work, but you are allowed finer grain control that the UITableView doesn't give you.

Checkout [this tutorial](https://www.objc.io/issues/3-views/collection-view-layouts/) for a brief primer on custom layouts for collection views. I recommend watching the 2012 WWDC video [Advanced Collection Views and Building Custom Layouts](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2012-219/) as well.

Comment: Great answer ! Loooks like a good solution. This will give me way more control. Thankyou. Haven't thought about it.

Comment: No problem. Alternatively if it's your desire to mimic the Primer application exactly, you're best bet would be to create your own navigation controller that uses [UIViewController containment](https://www.objc.io/issues/1-view-controllers/containment-view-controller/). Having UIViewControllers in either UITableViewCell's or UICollectionViewCell's can be hairy and is generally discouraged. For normal view's though, it's fine.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation`. It's a visual-only effect, so it won't mess up what the table view is trying to do with the cell's frame. Something like this (maybe in `viewDidScroll()`):

```
for cell in tableView.visibleCells() {
  let cellOffset = tableView.contentOffset.y * someMagicFormula
  cell.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, cellOffset)
}
```

Answer (score -2):

If you will use `UIScrollView`, instead of `UITableView` functionality, then you can enable pagination in `scrollView` (with adding custom views in it) with vertical bouncing effect.

Else If you want to use `UITableView`, you could use a `UIScrollViewDelegate` and implement something like this.

```
- (void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
                     withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity
              targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetOffset
{
  UITableView *tableView = (UITableView*)scrollView;
  NSIndexPath *topIndexPathAfterScrolling = [tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:*targetContentOffset];
  CGRect rect = [tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPathOfTopRowAfterScrolling];
  targetOffset->y=rect.origin.y;
}
```

Here you can adjust the scroll action at particular `contentOffset`: "targetOffset"

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. I already have the custom paging. And this is a swift question.